# sqlite delete code not working in database_handeler

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, delete-row

```
db!!.rawQuery("DELETE FROM $Cards_TABLE WHERE $Card_Parent_Board_Id='$CardParnt_boardId' AND $Card_Parent_Swimlane_Id='$CardParnt_SwimlaneId' AND $Card_Parent_List_Id='$CardParnt_ListId' ", null)
```

this code doesn't work in app
but the result string (sql code ) works in sql

Comment: Try using `execSQL` instead of `rawQuery` (iirc rawQuery only works if output is expected)

Comment: @MikeT    `execSQL` worked

Comment: @MikeT post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rawQuery` method expects output, that is it returns a Cursor, and should therefore only be used for SELECT queries.

Other queries, such as DELETE, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE or CREATE queries should instead use the **`execSQL`** method.

It should also be noted that the conveniences methods, such as `delete`, `insert` and `update` not only generate SQL but they also return the a useful value.

- The `insert` returns the **rowid** of the inserted row as a longm
- The `update` and `delete` methods return the number of affected rows as an int.

You may wish to refer to [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String))